# How to divide an image into a grid and access the pixel coordinates in each tile?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I want to divide a given image into a grid/tiles but want to retain the original pixel coordinates in each tile. This is important because I want to look up a particular pixel coordinate and get the tile number in which that pixel is found. For eg, I have divided an image into 4 tiles and the pixel I'm looking for is in the second tile, so I want my output as 0 1 0 0. I was thinking of using the image_slicer module to split the image but I don't know how to access the pixel coordinates in each tile. Below is a way to calculate the number of rows/columns when we input the no of slices that we require:

```
img= image
cols,rows= image_slicer.calc_columns_rows(4)
```

For getting the required o/p I was thinking of using the below:

```
hist, edge = np.histogram(pixel_tile, bins= [tile1,tile2,tile3,tile4])
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There does not seem to be any image_slicer in OpenCV.  What is the source of that routine.

Comment: I am using a separate module called image_slicer, its not a part of OpenCV (https://pypi.org/project/image-slicer/).